# Symfony map relation with common column

Tags: php, symfony

I have two table:

- Operations

  - id (primary)
  - operation_code (string, unique)
  - ...
- Mest

  - id (primary)
  - operation_code (string, not unique)
  - ...

Is it possible to map relation using the already existing column `operation_code` ?

I already tried to create  relation OneToMany using symfony `make:entity`, but it adds an `id` columns to keep track of relation. I want to keep the relations with operation_code.

I am using Symfony 4 with PHP 7.3.

Comment: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html

Comment: I'm sorry I must be blind, I can't find any documentation that suit my particular needs (using already existing columns). If you know where on the page it is located, could you help me please ? Sorry for needing assistance